# How can I effectively use If statements with multiple conditions in VBA, comparing user input to a range?

Tags: excel, vba, matching

I am attempting to create an Auto-grading test of sorts in Excel.

I have 5 values in `Sheet1` that are input by a user in cells `E5:E9`. These should then be compared against a range of 5 more cells in `Sheet2` (also cells `E5:E9`).

As the user might not always list these entries in the same order that I have in my Sheet2 range, I decided that I should loop through the range for each cell's input.

The next step would be to be able to ignore the value in the range once a match has been found but I need to get this part working correctly. Currently, the values absolutely match. However, I am not getting the correct output.

```
Sub Q1()

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 5 To 9
        If (Sheet1.Cells(5, 5) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 5)) And (Sheet1.Cells(6, 5) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 5)) And (Sheet1.Cells(7, 5) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 5)) And (Sheet1.Cells(8, 5) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 5)) And (Sheet1.Cells(9, 5) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 5)) Then
            Sheet1.Cells(5, 6) = 1
            Exit For
        Else
            Sheet1.Cells(5, 6) = 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I would expect the output of 1 to `Sheet1` cell `E6` but I am currently getting 0. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Damian. Not sure why it pasted over like that

Comment: Thought this is offtopic, once you paste your code, select it and press ctrl+k

Comment: I appreciate the info!

Comment: Could you please post images from the inputs and the desired output?

Comment: Maybe you can do it without a loop? The formula `=SUMPRODUCT(--$E$5='Sheet 2'!$E$5:$E$9))` will return 1 if E5 as a value equal to one in the range Sheet 2!E5:E9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little Complex :)

```
Sub Q1()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim chck(5 To 9) As Boolean

For i = 5 To 9

    For j = 5 To 9

        If Sheet1.Cells(i, 5) = Sheet2.Cells(j, 5) Then

            chck(i) = True
            Exit For
        Else: chck(i) = False

        End If
    Next

Next

j = 0

For i = LBound(chck) To UBound(chck)

    If chck(i) = True Then j = j + 1

Next

If j = 5 Then
Sheet1.Cells(5, 6) = 1
Else: Sheet1.Cells(5, 6) = 0
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Mikku you are a god

Comment: So the only piece that I am concerned with at this point is that a student could input a single correct value 5 times are still receive credit. Obviously there would be no reason to do this without knowledge of the code being used, but I am still curious to see if I can prevent that by having the sub ignore a range entry after a match is found. Any ideas?

Comment: It ignores once the match is found. Did you try the scenario that you are talking about ?

Comment: I did. I can currently put the same value in 5 times and still get an output of 1. I'll give it another look

Answer (score 0):

Does this really need to be VBA? A formula can perform this calculation. Use this in 'Sheet1' cell F5:

```
=--(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Sheet2!E5:E9,E5:E9))>0)
```

If at least one of the values in 'Sheet1'!E5:E9 (the user entered values) exists in your 'Sheet2'!E5:E9 list, the formula will return a `1` else `0` which is the desired result based on your description.